# regular expression to a word with an exact pettern

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I need a javascript regular expression to get all words that starts with ! and then is followed by any number of alpha-numerics 
for example if I have a text like

```
!google I don't like you I prefer !bi3g or !yahoo
```

I need a regular to return  ("!google", "!bi3g", "!yahoo")
I have this regular expresion `/\![a-z0-9 &-_] /gi` that will work perfectly in the case where the word is not followed by `\n` or isn't the end of the text, so applying it to the previous text it won't return "!yahoo"

I know that using `\b\b` will return all words including the ones followed by `\n` and the last word in the text can anybody help me how to set my regular expression to return **all words** inculding those follwed by `\n` and the last word in the text using `\b\b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "!google I don't like you I prefer !bi3g or !yahoo",
    words = str.match(/![^\s]+/g); //["!google", "!bi3g", "!yahoo"];
```

To also remove the `!` signs you can run

```
words = words.map(function(val) { return val.substr(1); });
```

(Note, `map()` is a feature of ECMAScript Edition 5; if you need support for IE <= 8 there are other ways of removing the `!`).